# Interfaz Iterator, uso en ArrayList. Java

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

Tengo entendido que cuando se implementa una interfaz se deben implementar todos los métodos que ésta contiene, puesto que los métodos declarados en una interfaz son abstractos y solo se declara la cabecera...
Es por eso por lo que no entiendo completamente cómo funciona el método **iterator()** perteneciente a la clase ***ArrayList***. Sé que devuelve una instancia de la interfaz ***iterator***, y esta instancia la podemos usar ***sin sobreescribir*** sus métodos ***hasNext(), next(), remove()***.
¿Por qué se pueden usar sus métodos si no los hemos sobreescrito y por lo tanto no les hemos dado un funcionamiento?
Un ejemplo:

```
Iterator <String> mi_iterador=lista.iterator();
 while(mi_iterador.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(mi_iterador.next());
 }
```

Este código funciona perfectamente pero yo en ningún momento he dado funcionamiento a los métodos mencionados anteriormente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase ArrayList implementa la interfaz Iterable, al implementarla sobreescribe el método `iterator()` que retorna un objeto de tipo Iterator, pero como tambien es una interfaz y se deben de implementar todos sus métodos, entonces es conveniente que se declare una clase abstracta, dentro de la clase ArrayList, que implemente la interfaz Iterator y ésta sería la que implementará todos sus métodos y podrá instanciar un objeto.

Resumen en código:

```
public class ArrayList implements Iterable<E> ...{

       private Miclase implements Iterator<E>{

       private Miclase(){
       }
       @Override
       public boolean hasNext(){}
       public E next(){}
       public void remove(){}
       //etc etc

       }

       @Override
       public Iterator<E> iterator(){
       Iterator<E> iterator = new Miclase();
       return iterator;

      }
}
```

Espero haber resuelto tu duda.

Comment: Entonces es la clase ArrayList la que sobreescribe el método iterator() y le da su funcionamiento, ¿no?

Comment: Por eso yo puedo usar el método iterator() desde el main de una clase cualquiera sin haber sobreescrito el método y haberle dado funcionamiento?

Comment: No es exactamente la clase ArrayList, es una clase abstracta declarada e implementada en la clase ArrayList.